# Is there a tool to interact with my app users directly?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, crashlytics, splunk

I am using Splunk Mint (or Crashlytics) for app management, I can se how many users are active, crashes in real time and some other info. Is there a tool to interact with users from this tools? For example I see that some users keep using a old buggy version, and I'd like to sugest them to update it.

p.s. I know, I can implement GCM and somehow analyse data and send push notifications, but it would be nice an simple one click solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may start with FCM as it is latest as well as has more features

follow link below:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

happy coding

Comment: does it have such an option?

Comment: yes, once you know appid of user you may send notification from firebase dashboard itself